# Using Regex to capture between brackets, that also contain a special character

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to use preg_replace to remove unwanted blocks of text that are encapsulated within brackets [ ], but only blocks of text that include a star or stars * anywhere inside the brackets [ * ]

for example:
blah blah blah blah [ blah ] blah blah [ blah * blah ] [] [ blah ] blah [ blah * blah * * blah ]

Of the above I want [ blah * blah ] and [ blah * blah * * blah ]

I have come as far as:

```
$new_string = preg_replace('/\[.*(\*).*\]/', '', $string);
```

but this escapes, or goes passed closing brackets and removes too much.

Comment: You want to substitute the match-all `.*` with something more specific, like »anything but square brackets« for matching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$new_string = preg_replace('/\[[^\]]*(\*)[^\]]*\]/', '', $string);
```

The difference is, that instead of some arbitrarily characters `.*` you look for some characters but closing brackets `[^\]]*` - this is necessary because the regexp is *greedy* and looks for the last closing bracket otherwise. A bit hard to read because of all the brackets, asterisks and escaping...

It will output

```
blah blah blah blah [ blah ] blah blah  [] [ blah ] blah
```

Comment: A great place to test this out and understand it in great detail is http://regex101.com/